# can not convert JSON to object

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

First of all I have searched the internet for a solution to my problem.
I have found several sites that can parse my JSON and tell me that it's valid. I knew that beforehand since it originates from my SQL Server.

But when calling JSON.parse(...) with the following json, I get a string back not a object!

My code so far:

```
function GetConfig(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    if (xhr.status === 200)
        return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    else
        return null;
};
/*
  xhr.responseText returns this JSON:
    {"graphSettings":{"Caption":"TEST","Min":2.850000000000000e+001,"Max":2.950000000000000e+001}}

*/

    function GenerateHighChart(ressponse) {       
         var data = GetConfig('/api/Settings/Powerlog/Temperatures');

    }
```

But when trying to access data as a object I get an error since data is still a string

```
var a = data.graphSettings.min;
```

**UPDATE**

I believe the problem is in my API

So here is my controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Settings")]
public class APIGetSettings : Controller
{
    private string InternalGetJson(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var json = GetJson(commandText, parameters);
        return json.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    }
    private string GetSettingFromName(string name) => InternalGetJson("select * from fn_GetVisualSettings(@0) for json path", name);

    [Route("Powerlog/Temperatures")]
    public IActionResult Powerlog_Temperatures() => new JsonResult(GetSettingFromName("Powerlog/Temperatures"));

}


   /*
    JSON returned from GetSettingFromName

      {"graphSettings":{"Caption":"TEST","Min":2.850000000000000e+001,"Max":2.950000000000000e+001}}

    */
```

in my Javascript if I change `GetConfig` to

```
if (xhr.status === 200)
    return JSON.parse(xhr.responseJSON);
else
    return null;

responseJSON is undefined
```

** UPDATE **

I found the bug. the problem is the text returned from my API

I get this :

```
"{\"graphSettings\":{\"Caption\":\"TEST\",\"Min\":2.850000000000000e+001,\"Max\":2.950000000000000e+001}}"
```

but expected this:

```
"{"graphSettings":{"Caption":"TEST","Min":2.850000000000000e+001,"Max":2.950000000000000e+001}}"
```

I'll create a new QUESTION

Comment: Your text represenation has the property `Min` (Pascal case), but you try to access `min` (camel case). Is that your problem?

Comment: Do you get an error while parsing the JSON to object, or while accessing the property `min`?

Comment: By the way .... do you see *Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience* in the console? Just wondering if that bothers you

Comment: @Oliver that might be an problem also but not the main problem singe I can not access "data.graphSettings"

Comment: @JaromandaX i didn't knew that (i don't know much about JavaScript) but since its only deprecated  it only means that I have to change it, it should make no diffrence to the result on the short path

Comment: `it only means that I have to change it, it should make no diffrence` actually it makes a very big difference to your code once you introduce *asynchrony* - asynchrony is like a virus that will spread through your synchronous code - better to design code allowing for asynchrony now, rather than refactoring hundreds of lines later when deprecated turns to unsupported - however, you're right, this has nothing to do with your *typo* (`min` !== `Min`)

Comment: @JaromandaX by later I meant later today ;)

Comment: Replacing xhr.responseText with what you claim the API returns and fixing the typo makes the code run just fine. Post what error you get and the rest of your code where you're trying to access the data and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Asgeirr I've updated my question.

Answer (score -2):

This is working:

```js
var x = {"graphSettings":{"Caption":"TEST","Min":2.850000000000000e+001,"Max":2.950000000000000e+001}}
console.log(x.graphSettings.Min);
```

Please log/debug the `xhr.responseText` and see whats there.

If you have any error, remember to post it here as well.

Comment: @Xufox - ah, true.

Comment: @JaromandaX - its not clear, he says he gets error, in case of typo with `Min/min` he would just get undefined.

Comment: he doesn't mention what error or where he gets it - but I agree - it's not clear at all :p

Comment: No!  no difference at all! The JSON didn't parse! It is still a string after the retrun of JSON.parse

Comment: @JensBorrisholt - What error do you get? What exact response you get if you log `xhr.responseText`. Please update the question with it.

Comment: @libik I don't get any errors but I believe the error is inside my API. I've updated the question

Comment: @JensBorrisholt - can you log me, what is inside `json` after this line? ` var json = GetJson(commandText, parameters);`

Comment: before replace: 
"[{\"graphSettings\":{\"Caption\":\"TEST\",\"Min\":2.850000000000000e+001,\"Max\":2.950000000000000e+001}}]"
after replace :
"{\"graphSettings\":{\"Caption\":\"TEST\",\"Min\":2.850000000000000e+001,\"Max\":2.950000000000000e+001}}"